# MATLAB Function to round an a number to nearest integer divisible by 5?

Tags: matlab, logic, matlab-guide

Is there any MATLAB Function to round an a number to nearest integer divisible by 5?

What I want to do it, let say I have numbers from 0.3,4.7,7.6 and I want these numbers to be rounded to 0, 5, 10. Is there any function in MATLAB to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can round to a multiple of 1, you can round to a multiple of N. Simply use

```
round(x/5)*5
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic would be like [not sure of the syntax of MATLAB]

```
floor((x + 2.5)/5)
```

**Edit:**

```
floor((x + 2.5)/5) * 5
```

Comment: @Geek well i missed out a `* 5` at the end; updated the answer. thanks for pointing out.